# Plot 3d in 2d with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d, 2d

I am unable to plot 3D figures on my Linux computer using Numpy, because my graphics card does not have Linux support and the company's driver is basic. Is there away to write the data of the 3D plot directly into a 2D image, such as a 2D plot or png file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`savefig()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) method on your plot. Matplotlib can create 3D figures even without a graphics card (such as on a web server), and you can then save the image directly to disk.

Comment: Thanks. May you provide a small example?

Comment: @linuxfreebird go to the matplotlib gallery, run any of the examples, but first append `plt.savefig('test.png')` to the script.

Comment: oh wait my program is using mayavi

Comment: ERROR: In /build/buildd/vtk-5.8.0/Rendering/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 631
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x68b49e0): Cannot create GLX context.  Aborting.

Comment: This will not work for me. I commented out the figure, to simply compile, but not plot, of which still generates the same driver error. I hate this graphics card.

Comment: It fails when I execute mlab.pipeline.volume(grid, vmin=min, vmax=max)